# AutocompleteTextView dropdown has empty space

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutocompleteTextView` that shows a dropdown using an `ArrayAdapter`. However when the dropdown opens, it extends till the bottom of the screen with a ton of extra whitespace. I want it to only extend till there are items in my list, and not beyond it.

Here's the view generation code inside the custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            ListitemServiceBinding binding = ListitemServiceBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);

            ServiceCategory serviceCategory = serviceCategoryList.get(position);
            if (serviceCategory != null)
            {
                bindData(binding, serviceCategory);
            }
            return binding.getRoot();
        }
        else
        {
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Is something wrong here?

This was working fine with the default `ArrayAdapter` implementation using the single line layout but once I put in a custom implementation, this started happening.

Answer (score 0):

In `getView()`, you are returning 2 contradicting views; the first is with dataBinding in `return binding.getRoot();`, and the second is without dataBinding with `return convertView`.

So, the dataBinding isn't implemented correctly here; instead you need to be consistent of the returned view

Another issue: You bind data only when the converView is null; but not the case when it isn't null.

You can fix that by implementing a `ViewHolder` that can hold a unique view that you can use in data binding:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ItemViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        ListitemServiceBinding binding = ListitemServiceBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        holder = new ItemViewHolder(binding);
        holder.view = binding.getRoot();
        holder.view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ServiceCategory serviceCategory = serviceCategoryList.get(position);
    if (serviceCategory != null) {
        bindData(holder.binding, serviceCategory); // should be holder.binding instead of binding
    }
    
    return holder.view;
}

private static class ItemViewHolder {
    private View view;
    private final ListitemServiceBinding binding;

    ItemViewHolder(ListitemServiceBinding binding) {
        this.view = binding.getRoot();
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}
```

Comment: The things you pointed out might be wrong too but I was able to fix the issue by something else. In my layout for the list item, when the root layout height was set to wrap content, the visual bug appeared. When I set it to a fixed height, it got fixed.

Comment: Nice, you can post it as an answer if you wish so that it might help future visitors

Comment: Did you modified the adapter to make it work?

Comment: No modifications to the adapter were needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. What worked is either:

- Setting fixed layout size in your item layout, like Asim mentioned
  or
- In your item layout TextView:

  ```
   android:maxLines="1"
  ```